# Notification to GCM using PHP curl

Tags: php, google-cloud-messaging

I am using curl to send notification to Multiple users in GCM. 
In a scenario if any user unregisterd/uninstalled the app from device I am getting failed message "UnRegistered" from curl response.any other solution to check if registerationid isvalid and send notification to users.

Curl code:

```
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data'  => array( "message" => $message )
    );
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
// Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();
    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $res = json_decode($result, true);


    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
```